# Error : The non-nullable type is 'ID' in Spring Boot with the usage of Graphql

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I just devised an example of **Spring Boot** with the usage of **Graphql**.

I tried to **update** the **department** by **id** but I got an error in **id** part.

Here is my **error** message which is shown below.

```
The field at path '/updateDepartment/hospital/id' was declared as a non null type, but the code involved in retrieving data has wrongly returned a null value.  The graphql specification requires that the parent field be set to null, or if that is non nullable that it bubble up null to its parent and so on. The non-nullable type is 'ID' within parent type 'Hospital'
```

Here are my **mutation** and **query variables** snippets which is shown below.

```
mutation updateDepartment($departmentInput: DepartmentInput!) {
  updateDepartment(id: 10,department: $departmentInput){
    name
    hospital{
      id
    }
  }
}

{
  "departmentInput": {
    "name": "Department 10 Update",
    "hospitalId": 3
  }
}
```

Here is my project link : [Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootgraphql)

How can I fix that error?

Comment: I can't reproduce your exception. I've downloaded your sources from GitHub an everything works as you expect.

Comment: @DanielWosch I am avoiding the error by not querying hospital/id in updateDepartment function as you can see my answer.

Comment: I have queried the hospital ID and did not received an error: `mutation updateDepartment {
  updateDepartment(
    id: 10,
    department: {
      hospitalId: 2
      name: "test12"
    }
  ) {
    name,
    hospital {
      id
    }
  }
} `

Comment: @DanielWosch You should use `DepartmentInput` instead of defining its variables.

Comment: Same behaviour: https://imgur.com/jZRekLh  Are you missing something in your posted example?

Comment: @DanielWosch I got this kind of error when I don't avoid to query hospital/id in here `hospital{
      id
    }`

Comment: Sure, that what I understand. But I have downloaded your coded, started it and executed your mutation as posted in the screenshot.

Comment: @DanielWosch Here is the screenshot : https://imgur.com/ZQ7QqHQ This is my problem.

Comment: @DanielWosch I wait your feedback

Comment: That makes no sense to me tbh. Using GraphiQL everything works as it should. Have you tried to debug and verify that there is not something other missing

Comment: @DanielWosch I added my screenshot as you can see. There is a nullable error in hospital/id. How can I fix it?

Comment: Sure, GraphQL is returning you this error. But have you debugged your code to check if hospital is not null or that the hospital.getId() in department is not null?

Comment: @DanielWosch I already debugged `updateDepartment` method but I cannot fix it. Can you debug this method if you don't mind?

Comment: I did but as I said: I can not reproduce your error therefore it makes no sense for me to debug this method again.

Comment: @DanielWosch Here is the link : https://imgur.com/okdpMo3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my **solution**

**Mutation**

```
mutation updateDepartment($departmentInput: DepartmentInput!) {
  updateDepartment(id: 10,department: $departmentInput){
    name
  }
}
```

**Query Variables**

```
{
  "departmentInput": {
    "name": "Department 10 Update",
    "hospitalId": 3
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are just avoiding the error by not querying hospital/id. To solve the issue either make sure hospital/id exists (not null) and available to return for all possible input or make that field nullable by updating the schema.

Comment: @MatG How can I fix that issue? Is it possible to write that code you mentioned?

Comment: @MatG Can you help me how to fix my issue?

Comment: You can log the department just before returning from the resolver and check if all values are returned correctly.

Comment: @MatG it throws stackoverflowerror error when I update it